# What is the maximum value of $f(\theta) = \sin\theta \cos\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the maximum value of $f(\theta) = \sin\theta \cos\theta$ ?

Comment: $1/2$ is the max value

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $1$:
$\sin \theta \cdot \cos \theta = \dfrac{\sin 2\theta}{2}$

**Hint** $2$:

$\sin \theta \cdot \cos \theta \leq \dfrac{\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Choose the hint you like most...

Answer (score 2):

*Alternative hint:* $ab \leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin\theta\cos\theta=\frac{\sin2\theta}2$$ and for real $\theta,-1\le\sin2\theta\le1$

W/o using double angle formula, $$\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta(1-\sin^2\theta)=\frac{1-\left(\sin^2\theta-\dfrac12\right)^2}4\le\frac14$$

Answer (score 0):

Using AM-GM inequality is the best way.